# Android: Call method at specific timestamp

Tags: java, android, time

How do I call a method at a specific timestamp(in milliseconds) specifically in the base of System.currentTimeMillis() ?

Comment: [6. The ScheduledExecutorService Interface](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial#ScheduledExecutorService)

Comment: @akuzminykh Android recommends, if you are working on UI Thread, to use Handler instead of creating new Threads

Comment: @Tano Can you cite a reference for that recommendation? I see [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code) showing how to run code on background threads. Of course, one cannot access UI widgets from any background thread, as the Android [documentation explains](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui).

Comment: It depends what you need, you need to execute heavy/intensive backround work, is better to use Threads, like you posted, if you need, for example show a text in the UI after a couple of seconds, then better user Handler
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui#Handler

Answer (score 1):

I hope I get your question right!

You can calculate first the **delay** from your timestamp: (assumimg `yourGivenTimestamp` is in the future)

```
long yourGivenTimestamp = 1594139504827;
long delay = yourGivenTimestamp - System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and then pass it to `postDelayed()` method in a `Handler` instance:

```
new handler().postDelayed(() -> myFancyMethod(), delay);
```

Then your `myFancyMethod()` will be executed when the `delay` time is passed

### UPDATE

Android has deprecated `Hanlder()` constructor (without parameter).

Please use `new Handler( Looper.getMainLooper() )` or `new Handler( Looper.myLooper() )` instead. More [info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler())

Answer (score 1):

## `ScheduledExecutorService`

Keep a [scheduled executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) object around.

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
```

Calculate time to wait.

```
Instant then = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_594_139_504_827L ) ;
Instant now = Instant.now() ; 
Duration d = Duration.between( now , then ) ;
if( d.isNegative() ) { … error … going back in time }
```

Define your task as a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). You can use [lambda syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) as seen here, or use conventional syntax.

```
Runnable runnable =
        ( ) -> {
            System.out.println( "Doing some task. " + Instant.now() );
        };
```

Submit to the executor service. Specify the task, a quantity of time to wait until running that task, and the [unit of that quantity of time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) (milliseconds, seconds, hours, or such).

```
ses.schedule( runnable , d.toSeconds() , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

Your runnable runs on a background thread. Never access the user interface from a background thread. See Android documentation: [*Communicate with the UI thread*](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui).

Be sure to gracefully shutdown your executor service before your app ends. Otherwise the backing thread pool may run indefinitely.

This has all been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.